# Issues Pulling in world.json to render map using D3

Tags: github, d3.js, jsfiddle

I'm in the process of using JSFiddle to start demo'ing a collection of D3 visualizations and discovered that you can now pull directly from a github repository.  I've put together the following [JSFiddle repository](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/D3/3.0.4/jkeohan/d3_map_github/tree/master/Demo) to render a world map which is configured to pull in a world.json file as follows:

```
 d3.json("world.json", function(error, world) {
      svg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.subunits).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
      .attr("d", path)
        .style({
          stroke:"white",
          "stroke-width": 0.75,
          fill: "lightgrey"
          })
    });
```

It pulls in most of the files but is unable to GET the world.json file which is needed to render the map and I see the following error in console:
    GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/world.json 404 (NOT FOUND)

Any ideas on how to resolve the GET issue and successfully pull the world.json data?

Joe

Comment: Where is `world.json` actually stored?

Comment: Seems like the error message is pretty self-explanatory. The GeoJSON file doesn't exist at that URL. You need to supply the correct URL.

Comment: world.json is stored in the github repository as all the other files...https://github.com/jkeohan/d3_map_github/tree/master/Demo

Comment: You'll need to update the path in the json request to use the URL as specified by jsfiddle for github AJAX requests.  it's something like `/gh/get/response.json/jkeohan/d3_map_github/tree/master/Demo/`, which as per http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_response.html will load the demo_response.json file.  Not sure if you can load arbitrary files from github through jsfiddle.  I tried that with your fiddle and I get a 403 being returned with `Please use only with Ajax requests` in the response.  Something is interfering with the AJAX request in this case, by the looks.